# How to browse container files in Docker for Windows? My folder mapping didn't work

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt

I run Windows machine and I'm super new to docker, I'm trying to setup LetsEncrypt on my site for HomeAssistant purpose.

I create a folder in C:/Docker/LetsEncrypt in my Windows machine and then I run this command.

```
PS C:\Users\test> docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 --name certbot -v "C:Docker/LetsEncrypt/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt" -v "C:Docker/LetsEncrypt/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt" -v "C:Docker/LetsEncrypt/var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt" quay.io/letsencrypt/letsencrypt:latest certonly --standalone --standalone-supported-challenges http-01 --email myemail@mail.com -d mysite.duckdns.org
```

This is the result I got

```
Warning: This Docker image will soon be switching to Alpine Linux.
You can switch now using the certbot/certbot repo on Docker Hub.
The standalone specific supported challenges flag is deprecated. Please use the --preferred-challenges flag instead.
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
/opt/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/josepy/jwa.py:107: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: signer and verifier have been deprecated. Please use sign and verify instead.
  signer = key.signer(self.padding, self.hash)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please read the Terms of Service at
https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf. You must
agree in order to register with the ACME server at
https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(A)gree/(C)ancel: a

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Would you be willing to share your email address with the Electronic Frontier
Foundation, a founding partner of the Let's Encrypt project and the non-profit
organization that develops Certbot? We'd like to send you email about EFF and
our work to encrypt the web, protect its users and defend digital rights.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(Y)es/(N)o: y
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for mysite.duckdns.org
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.duckdns.org/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on 2018-06-22. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot
   again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
   "certbot renew"
 - Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot
   configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a
   secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will
   also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so
   making regular backups of this folder is ideal.
 - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
```

Looks like everything is fine except I can't find the file `fullchaim.pem` and `privkey.pem` in my Windows machine which is suppose to be inside C:\Docker\LetsEncrypt\etc\letsencrypt.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command you executed

```
PS C:\Users\test> docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 --name certbot 
    -v "C:Docker/LetsEncrypt/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt" 
    -v "C:Docker/LetsEncrypt/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt" 
    -v "C:Docker/LetsEncrypt/var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt" 
    quay.io/letsencrypt/letsencrypt:latest 
    certonly --standalone --standalone-supported-challenges 
    http-01 --email myemail@mail.com -d mysite.duckdns.org
```

docker allows you to mount directories on our local machine such that internal to the launched container those same directories are mapped to new names however the directory contents are identical. For example in above it says

```
    -v "C:Docker/LetsEncrypt/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt"
```

which is a volume pair where left of `:` delimiter is a directory local to your machine  `C:Docker/LetsEncrypt/etc/letsencrypt` and on right hand side is what that same directory gets called from perspective inside container as per `/etc/letsencrypt` ... this mapping frees up the container's internal perspective to be isolated from a given person's local directory structure ... now look closely at this message :

```
- Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
```

that is from perspective of inside the container ... so now your are armed with the knowledge to discover where you missing keys are

***SOLUTION***  when inside of container it says

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
```

that same file is mapped to your local machine at location

```
C:Docker/LetsEncrypt/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.duckdns.org/fullchain.pem
```